# How to debug why an onload does not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This is a test code. It is suppose to show "How are you doing today? Buddy", but it does not show anything on the page right now and console does not say anything. Anyone knows why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function demo() {
      let newPara = window.document.createElement("p");
      newPara.innerHTML = "<h1>How are you doing today? Buddy</h1>";
      document.body.append(newPara);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div onload="demo()">


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: <body onload="demo()">

Comment: ^^ That.  There's no onload event for a div.

Comment: Also note that `append()` doesn't work at all in IE or Edge

Comment: You've included jquery and tagged jquery, but not used jquery (unless you were thinking your `.append()` was jquery, in which case change to `$("body").append(newPara)`)  (other issues not withstanding)

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach `onload` event on `div`.
You can attach it to `body` element.